# mCustomScrollbar scrollbar display on hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen answers on here on how to do this, but I just can't get it to work. Maybe another set of eyes will help. I'm trying to get the scrollbar to appear in a div that popups when an image is clicked.  Here's the code for that:
    
('modalcs' is the name of the div that pops up)

And the function:

```
 function update_scroll(theID) 
 {
   document.getElementById(theID).style.display = 'block';
   $(".scrollable").mCustomScrollbar("update");
 }
```

In my `$(document).ready(function()` I have:

```
$(".scrollable").mCustomScrollbar({
  theme:"dark-thick",
  scrollButtons:{
  enable:true,
  advanced:{  
  updateOnBrowserResize:true,   
  updateOnContentResize:true   
  }
 }
});
```

and I understand that on page load since the hidden div isn't seen, the scrollbar is unable to see its content.

TIA for any help!

Comment: Thanks @Prateek for the edit. This is my first ever post! Your edit is definitely prettier than mine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "update" command does not operate on a collection, so if  $(".scrollable") returns more than one element, it will update only the first one. Use `$.each`

```
$(".scrollable").each(function(){
   $(this).mCustomScrollbar("update");
});
```

On the other hand, since you are operating on 1 element, you can just change your function:

```
function update_scroll(theID) 
 {
   $('#' + theID).show().mCustomScrollbar("update");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Darhazer! Your solution didn't exactly work for me, but it got me headed in the right direction. I ended up using:
function update_scroll(theID)
{
    $('#' + theID).show();
    $(".scrollable").mCustomScrollbar("update");
}